# Entity Framework - Read Updates before saving

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In EF 6, When i make an update on a record in a Entity, Before saving the changes by calling _context.SaveChanges(), I should be able to access this updated record along with the other records in a different function to be able to validate the change.

```
public bool UpdateToFlase(int id, int accountNumber)
{
    var charge = _context.CHARGES.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id == id).Active = False;
    if(!IsValid(accountNumber))
        return false;
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return true;
}

public bool IsValid(int accountNumber)
{
    return _context.CHARGES.Where(x=>x.AccountNumber == accountNumber && x.Active).Sum(x=>x.Charge) >=0;
    
    //I noticed that the above update that i made is only in _context.CHARGES.Local and by accessing _context.CHARGES, 
    //i'm unable to access the updates. I was hoping to find a way to access records along with the updated one.
}


Given:
    Id  AccountNumber   Charge  Active
    1   10001           100     True
    2   10001           -100    True
    
When
    UpdateToFalse(1, 10001)
Then
    Actual:
        return TRUE
    Expected:
        return FALSE

Expectation 
    In IsValid function, (-100 >= 0) should return false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are trying to access an entity which is loaded into your dbset collection in your context, which will not be 'updated' untill you invoke

```
 SaveChanges()
```

I believe this is because EF is tracking each entity from when you first loaded them in your collection. I think it won't be 'updated' untill you 'update' it when you call SaveChanges()

Maybe you could try passing the modified entity to the isValid function and possibly modify the isValid function so that it can check the value you are trying to save?

Maybe this article can help you out to prevent the unwanted entity to be saved in the database:

https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/entity-state-in-entity-framework/

Answer (score 0):

I took modified and removed entities like this

```
            var modifiedEntities = _context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                .Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Modified || p.State == EntityState.Deleted)
                .ToList();

            foreach (var change in modifiedEntities)
            {
                Validate(change);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach that worked:

```
public bool UpdateToFlase(int id, int accountNumber)
{
    var charge = _context.CHARGES.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id == id).Active = False;
    if(!IsValid(_context.CHARGES.Where(x=>x.AccountNumber == accountNumber).ToList()))
        return false;
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return true;
}

public bool IsValid(List<CHARGES> charges)
{
    return charges.Where(x=>/*What ever the criteria is */ x.Active).Sum(x=>x.Charge) >=0;
    
    //This way, we are referring to same scope as the above function 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This would not account for concurrent requests but assuming that is not an issue what you could do is the following:

```
public bool IsValid(int id, int accountNumber)
{
    return _context.CHARGES.Where(x=>x.AccountNumber == accountNumber && x.Active && x.Id != id).Sum(x=>x.Charge) >=0;
}
```

What you are trying to do is get the total of all the active charges except the one you want to make inactive so in the above that charge is specifically excluded.

The way you are trying to do it won't work as the database isn't updated until you call `SaveChanges()`.

Comment: I added a sample code in my question. In realtime, I'm updating many collections and trying to validate all those collections in ``IsValid`` function.